# Compare version numbers

Tags: code-golf, string, number

When we publish some software, we assign a version number to it. And users may want to update to the latest version of some software. So, it is the time to find out which version should be newer.

#### Input

Input two version numbers as strings.

In the context of this challenge, we only support version numbers which are some digits joined by dots.

- A version number is a non-empty string which may only contain digits (`0` ~ `9`) and dots (`.`).
- Dots would not be the first / last character of a version number.
- There must be some digits between dots. No two dots may appear continuously.
- All numbers in a version number would be less than 2<sup>16</sup>.

#### Output

Compare the inputted version numbers and output whether first one is greater than / equals to / less than the second one. You are allowed to choose one of the following presentations:

- Use positive number / zero / negative number, while zero means equal;
- Use three constant distinct values;

#### Comparing

You are not required to implement the algorithm described in this section. Your submission is valid as long as it result the same output with this algorithm.

- Version numbers are some decimal numbers joined by dots. We first split the two version numbers to arrays of numbers;
- Padding the ending of arrays with zeros to make them have same length;
- Compare from the first item to the last one:

  - If the two array items different, the greater number means greater version number
  - If they are the same, continue to compare the following items;
  - If all items in the array are equal, the two versions are equal.

#### Testcases

```
version1  version2  result
2         1         >
1.0.0     1         =
1.0       1.0.0     =
1.2.42    1.2.41    >
1.1.56789 1.2.0     <
1.10      1.2       >
1.20      1.150     <
18.04     18.4      =
7.010     7.8       >
1.0.0.1.0 1.00.00.2 <
00.00.01  0.0.0.1   >
0.0.1     0.1       <
42.0      4.2.0     >
999.999   999.999.1 <
2018.08.1 2018.08   >
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47098/31625), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/33003/31625)

Comment: .NET has a Version object, but a single character isn't supported in it :(

Comment: @BrianJ and appending '.0' costs to many characters? :)

Comment: Well, it actually expects 2, 3, or 4 portions. So it fails on the 1.0.0.1.0 test case (though I did try your idea initially :) )

Comment: I think Windows has a built-in that'll do this: StrCmpLogicalW

Comment: I wanted to use php's `version_compare`, but it returns the wrong results for any test cases where the versions differ by trailing zeroes

Comment: What is the maximum number of dots one can expect in a version number?

Comment: @jayce I’m not limiting this, so it may be any length while your submission should work in theory (it is fine to fail due to some limitations from hardware or language if the length is reasonable large)

Comment: Can we take input as an array of numbers without dots (e.g. `"1.0.0" -> [1, 0, 0]`)?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I don't think it may be acceptable. Since no one may write version numbers like `[1, 0, 0]`. Parsing version number should be a part of this challenge.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>84</s> <s>79</s> 76 bytes

```python
lambda*l:cmp(*map(lambda v:map(int,v.split('.')+[0]*len(`l`))[:len(`l`)],l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDhasMgFIX/7ymE/biahYtKupjQ7kXaQtOtZQWTSRsKffpMo7FJsy4Y8Fw/z/Uec2u/fxrZHVebTlf1/qtKdPlZG5rUlaG@Qq6lE6emTa94MfrUUkBgb2u@TfShoTu9Y2xdDtttqhnrzNny5EhBAglfSkBEwV4JfMBLxARy5PAntppicHeLd@aYxKzv3GNW9JbzpgIX77kqIGB3t@UUC109Bs9GkGNMLJ64KeRZnFSh389GyJGLGEiOCv7JDV0sPhDuloTHpr7ObQoW4/4OzN2GOvGYGDUdu2VDUg7LJrmN3YqiQPtDjwVhPR/dJHeRKHtisSCGt3W/)

Outputs `-1,0,1` for `<,=,>`

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'.¡0ζε`.S}0K¬
```

Outputs `-1  []  1` for `<  =  >` respectively.

-1 byte thanks to *@Emigna*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fXe/QQoNz285tTdALrjXwPrTm//9odUM9Az1DIDRQ11EAcQz0jIDsWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##VY5BCsIwEEX3nqJ0M5syzITEJqtuRBCXLktBBY/h1gN4A/fd6gF6gB7Ci0STmViEBP5/@T98cqczXyK77W7T1dX7dq/qLgJOD5pf8/OIhyvtpzE2sQcDTQUMw6oHRkL6s9lkKsCglXxSJcXo1q0PhZcsa9uUrnp2mvBINiOPNpMWSUot@mUQLjsoHflPNHF6IYkJzypDAdZI3f6mhRDwexNUqVFDaZPXX9XB8AE).

**Explanation:**

```
'.¡              # Split on dots
                 #  i.e. ['1.0.1.1.0','1.00.2.0']
                 #   → [['1','0','1','1','0'],['1','00','2','0']]
   0ζ            # Zip, swapping rows and columns, using '0' as filler
                 #  i.e. [['1','0','1','1','0'],['1','00','2','0']]
                 #   → [['1','1'],['0','00'],['1','2'],['1','0'],['0','0']]
     ε   }       # Map each:
      `          #  Push both values to the stack
       .S        #  And calculate the signum (1 if a>b; -1 if a<b; 0 if a==b)
                 #   i.e. [['1','1'],['0','00'],['1','2'],['1','0'],['0','0']]
                 #    → [0,0,-1,1,0]
          0K     # Remove all zeros
                 #  i.e. [0,0,-1,1,0] → [-1,1]
            ¬    # Then take the head as result
                 #  i.e. [-1,1] → -1
```

Comment: You can use `0K` instead of `ʒĀ}`.

Comment: @Emigna Ah of course.. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 32 bytes

```r
rank(numeric_version(scan(,"")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLbaoQwEEDf/YoheVGwQxLcqtDdx/5EKUVEW2kbi7r7@3ZyMeq6wcBkPDkzDg4zf73qeup6Xf3ArRlGiqDtB5iacer0JzzB9NXAm3yHboT@z5FRe4bW34tvyVDp71hff5uhqz@8hNIJp2vzw5djXek4ZSxJkpkpIQsUBUoGS8yiiAMokEDLtHMxZ4knu33ubHNEueNLBFEb1zFTLAUmyQ2HxUlkGYkCBUsfYZzEC2MIS95RG0ZhpixGwc62qUVNP@dF6bGNjVPXC@OKqUNDG49yjDzdN7R6aHqZgQrMDozvOUdhi@VYHL9rOx8MExDm8a2FWi4rJCHC4UEXPC5tAHms5T2ZsmWy/Wj2nrIskTZhPlp9wbP@R2n4jwJzmf8B)

Using an R builtin

Outputs `1 2`, `1.5 1.5`, `2 1` for less, equal, greater.

---

Best so far, without builtin :

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>151 142 125</s> 107 bytes

```r
function(v,L=strsplit(v,'\\.'))Find(c,sign(Reduce('-',Map(as.double,Map(c,L,Map(rep,0,rev(lengths(L))))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDLioMwFIb3PkXQhRHSQxJsVRgL3czKmcWsu@lo7Aii4qWvb2OSeqkTFE/C5/efnHbM4zEfqrQv6go/SBJ3fds1ZdHLjXu9gut5n0WV4ZR0xb3CPyIbUoHdg0u@bg2@dZDVw28p1C4lifq2oiGUtOKBS1Hd@78OJ55Zo4MQQ3ndorPloO@LKmNZHvTph4WsHKfY5jZBNrM9D@2WI/9VDAMK1Cb/YY6UvpiJUOQbtWI4@FxhstjYVlkMjqcgjAy2sjmy6xejw/iuoZWHa4Yd3xtaPCFQf4JC8HeM6TkAqsICCPf3Ws8H5gnQ6TGtzVn6lDKJUI3PutmjjyeA7bOMx@cqxt@OZuuJogjkKzFTLb7Zw@l0@1DlmXphzuMT)

Unrolled code with explanation :

```r
function(v){             # character vector of 2 elements as function arg;
  L=strsplit(v,'\\.')    # obtain a list of two character vectors
                         # with the separated version numbers;
  R=rev(lengths(L))      # store in vector R the lengths of the 2 vectors and reverse it;
  M1=Map(rep,0,R)        # create a list of 2 vector containing zeros
                         # repeated R[1] and R[2] times;
  M2=Map(c,L,M1)         # append to the vectors in list L the zeros in M1;
  M3=Map(as.double,M2)   # convert the character vectors in M2 to double;
  w=sign(Reduce('-',M3)  # compute the sign of element by element difference M[[1]] - M[[2]]);
  Find(c,w)            # returns the first non zero element in w, if none return NULL;
}
# N.B. as.double is necessary because "0XX" is interpreted as octal by strtoi unless 
#      we use strtoi(x,10) which is exactly the same length of as.double(x)
```

Outputs `-1`, `NULL`, `1` for less, equal, greater.

---

Original concept, golfed down using `sapply`, `[<-` and `%*%`:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 129 bytes

```r
function(x,y=strsplit(x,"\\."),w=sign(sapply(y,function(x)strtoi("[<-"(rep(0,max(lengths(y))),seq(x),x),10))%*%c(1,-1)))w[!!w][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDRioMwEEXf9yvSLIXJkg5JSFeF9S/2zfZBRFvBVde4WL/eTaLUFBKYe@6d0cmwVOlS/bXFWHctPPicmnEwfVOPVtDLBSnjU2rqWwsm7/tmhpnvcWbDY1cDzb5OFIayB8F/8gc0ZXsb7wZmxhg35a9NcnukYOz4cSxA8pO01pQdDtM1k9elggKoopxQSRl781KiQEH5K3Ha850p1MpjW4RZiefPKE42K@yQ6xgVDlmRPAe5GIV2NEb9hBEK3x1hbBkh7@T7XpKhzE3XkqobyPYiuVs22AOf/y7c2T@9aiGtKdbgbnnl@M608nP0y0ZJkqC9lm9V0KCE2yP2g7baess/)

Now you have a list of two equal-length vectors of integers. Calculate the pairwise differences using `Reduce` and output the first non-zero element using the tricky little `w[!!w][1]` form at the end.

Outputs `-1`, `NA`, `1` for less, equal, greater.

Comment: Impressive! Quick golf: extra newline at the end of your code - it should be 150 bytes ;)

Comment: [reduce the number of named variables...](https://tio.run/##VY/RaoMwFIbv9xRpdpNAekiCrUrnS4zdWcHgtBVcFGOxMvbsLsZSU0jg/N9//pOcfq6SubrpYqhbTe5sSszQm66pByvw@QyYsjEx9UWTz/L7VpQk3@esUV3XTGRiW5L@qiRvSn0Zrh/73IZ/1J2s2pCJUnpSaW1AK6JolvCTfWZoa6KY4PTP2nRMd7sxS0U2V6QgWGKGsMCUvjkpgAPH7JUs2vGNSQikw7bwewUcjmEUPyw/IdYx0h@yInHw@iLgwUIjCJ4wBO7SIUSWIfSOvq4l6ktlWo2qtkf@kt4e8Pw7X8729Kq5sCZfGzfLqYVvLJBuTvCyURzHYK/lj8oLSL7sEblBj9p68z8). I feel there is a way to do it using a matrix instead of lists but I haven't found how to do it yet.

Comment: @JayCe the problem is the usual ways to make a list into a matrix recycles rather than fills with `NA`, so then you're stuck with counting the number of `.` in advance.

Comment: You can get this down to 100 bytes using `scan` `function(a,b,d=scan(t=a,se='.'),e=scan(t=b,se='.'),f=1:max(lengths(list(d,e))),g=d[f]-e[f])g[!!g][1]` (or 106 if you want to return -1,NA,1 not (negative),NA,(positive).

Comment: @mnel that is a clever use of `scan` !

Comment: @ngm: `w[!!w][1] is great !` [I got 125](https://tio.run/##VZDNjoIwFIX3PkXFRS9JvWkbVEhk3mB2szBBFqgFSQyQFnh9pi1GsGmTc777097qqUyncmjufd02MIamrhqAKlUvuJz3v0UHhcFHO9xeiplem@5V99AVplccRke06oAip0yrEZr7s9BQmeEG9Hp9UEYpG0O3mPVIrdhfskzmeZhtt1WeiTycdoQIUpeE/tCN1dzr1On9zM90synhDoEMGAlEEIazFciRB@ybOO/5wiRG0mMr1rkCD8dTnLxD6woxt5HrJjMSh1VejDxyNMboA0/IffUJY8sI2ZG/pyJaFaZtSNlqYv@sb2somODrOfDzdu72cvXsubBBPicuIe8cX1gkfZ/oa6IkSdAey99qVSC5myP2jd7axqZ/ "R – Try It Online") but with the use of scan is better !

Comment: @mnel the 100 byte solution needs a little work. It fails on the last two test cases. The padding has to be `0` and not (implictly) `NA`. I've made the answer a Community Wiki so whoever can fix it up can just add it.

Comment: @ngm @mnel @digemall I have golfed your original approach to 129 bytes :) I have asked in a comment to the OP whether we can assume an upper bound to the number of dots - that we could use in place of `max(lengths(y))`.

Comment: assuming for instance it,s capped at `4^9` we get to [117 chars](https://tio.run/##VZDhaoMwFIX/7ynSjEIy0ksS0mlgvsX@2Q5EtBOKusThfHqXRGlSSOCe75x79casbbG2v309dUNP/thS2MnY8d5NTuDLBTBlc2G7W09sNY73hSwsxqkLT0NHcPlxwsQ0I@FMfWnKbPPjXOaO4JQe3441EewkKKVzeTjM11Jc15bUBEvMEBaY0pcgBXDgmD0TrwOPTIKSAbsizQo4v2e53q20Q2xjZDpkQ@Kc5HLgytMc1ANmwEN3BrljCL2iz@8GmaayQ4/awaD9FSq/bLIHPP6d@xM/vWkunMm3YLSC8jwyJcMc9bSR1hrcdXyvkgbJ/R55GLTXzlv/AQ)

Comment: @JayCe: 111 bytes with no assumptions (question updated), but if that assumption is valid, maybe we can save something more :)

Comment: @digEmAll still waiting for an asnwer from OP.... assuming the max number of dots in 8 (9 integers separated by 8 dots) the best I can achieve by tweaking your code is [110](https://tio.run/##bZDLboMwEEX3fIVjFtiSsWyLFJBCpO5DF92SLFICFVIElEfz@XQwhEeoZctXo@N7x1N1adClbR43WZGTXxYG4bVkp6Buqrq8Zw2UrPOZW5TW2XdOyCP4TG5tnBDLtlhIrjW/Fe3XPQGNo4ON4a6SkgnmU5B18sNOFDasaLd7XCJ5oZ2JkERpUaGjYaKPdy0DkPZQPRjISElMsMIMYYkpRZtlwlvNSC64wOw/zATTJ9MTmnyhFozijtIYiJXbIkvy/Zvr@SO2cDOh6yczhKlNQwsfNTBy/9rQ7ONx4fSQx50NM/bscqHDXO5t/7WcD58mIPo9tjZlDVUhAREDPtlNPkO5B@Q2a/RxlI5x1qNZ@/i@z@EANqrZb/JRov@9p/NGPTPH7g8)

Comment: @digEmAll golfed 4 bytes by first calculating the sign , and then do `Find(c,x)`. I think that's a new trick.

Comment: @JayCe: indeed, great trick !

Comment: @JayCe: find several builtin... compareVersion unfortunately doesn't work as requested in case of different lengths (e.g. 1.0.0 vs 1.0), but numeric_version does :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82178/discussion-between-jayce-and-digemall).

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>63 47</s> 22 bytes

```perl6
{"v$^a cmp v$^b".EVAL}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/RaoMwFIbv8xQHGUPZOD0JaY2oZbvY3e4Gu7EObFEY1FWqDIrYV3dJY8K2YODjy5/jn64@Hzdze4H7BvJ5DL7vPio4tB1o2Af48v78Os0p04Gnoe6HHnI4fn7VPbZVF454OLX7cLV7e1hFU5Qy1pzOLjgygL66QBNiQeUjFryMrsFuCK5YiDJl0yzALe5pyzgS0j@bG@uy/txYgVJYq4m7CRzXm1glN2uzmbHkJohffxPe8rXPKiRprULpOsRIy4gY1d@@aPrpTeYTeoIl0o3Int@yjox1r8uYdCVB@r5bliQJ6q15IX0jY4JMN6V5IZP9AQ)

Turns out that Perl 6 has a [version type](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Version) that pretty much fits the description. This is an anonymous code block that takes a list of two version strings and returns either `More`,`Same` or `Less`.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                    }  # Anonymous code block
 "             "        # Create a string of code
  v$^a cmp v$^b         # Comparing the two versions
                .EVAL   # And EVAL it
```

### Or, without built-in types for 47 bytes:

```perl6
{first +*,[Z<=>] map *.split('.')[^@_.ords],@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/dioMwEIXv8xRDL1ptZZoEWxV/8B32bq1bursKglYx3ixiX91Nqgm7DRk4fHNmctIVfX2emx/YlhDPY1n1YoDD3sneozjJobl1sEfR1dVg7XBnZx/pFdv@W@ROep3UXDoUYhAQQ13dC4FywBrxq20@rePl7XC0Jzsk4qZ9ISFl2@uhkQCoXmlhRnMHMGO5/dhchs0DM56HZJo56MOMSghDivSFxopqr@krytHlC5WK6Q0MT2fPD5508UaKUr2B/3mNG8pOxusjdRfqo6szeEjXFR76//OiyieLqsvlhkVRmYgu/adXK0X17yLi6pDgmrwJCYIAZUm9KjkREU5VNl/qVSnvLw)

Anonymous code block that takes two strings and returns `More` if the second is greater, `Less` if the second is smaller and `Nil` if they are equal.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                             } # Anonymous code block
                 map *.split('.')          ,@_  # Split both strings by '.'
                                 [^@_.ords]     # Pad the lists by a lot
          [Z<=>]   # Zip the strings with the <=> operator
 first +*,  # Get the first value that when coerced to an int, is not 0
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @Adám for using `⍤1` instead of `∘↑(...)¨` and by changing the input format from a nested array to a matrix*

```apl
(⍋-⍒)(⍎¨∊∘⎕D⊆⊢)⍤1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU5LCsIwEF17kjZghySkNtl7kYLUTUG3XqCUSsUKgmtx0XP0KHORmDafRoRMeJ@ZxyvPdXa4lPXpqHWFzT3F/pph/yAG3KYR2w7bF96ee@wa7N4E@w/TGpuhMmYzTGOabhOeEPOzhJDNTBlQoH@SFazlRQ7C3c4w2maQ7wqpghfdMJ/EoxyvsXzdlECFlSUIrxZAXUAB8qcwRB3p/EK@pZQtLrW7wbNkQUEU3EWJuLpSCswshsPrCadzX@myHDPmFw)

Takes the input as a matrix of chars as the right argument, where each version string is on its own row. Outputs `¯1 1`, `0 0`, `1 ¯1` for `<`, `=`, `>` respectively.

`(⍎¨∊∘⎕D⊆⊢)⍤1` on each row

- `∊∘⎕D⊆⊢` group all occurrences of digits, that is, split on `.`
- `⍎¨` and convert each of these occurrences to a number

`↑` convert to a matrix, where the first input is on the top row and the second one in the bottom, padding with `0`s where necessary

`(⍋-⍒)` and

- `-` subtract

  - `⍒` the indices into the rows which would sort them in descending order
  - `⍋` same as the top but for ascending order

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>201</s> <s>96</s> 89 bytes

```java
java.util.Comparator.comparing(java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor.Version::parse)::compare
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNNa@MwEL33VwyGELukg2zSxnGaXnavPRX2UnLQOnKqrL@QZMNS8tuz@nKd2gsWHs1782YGzZxpTx/Oxz9XXrWNUHDWd@wUL7Ho6lzxpsb73V3b/S55DnlJpYRXymv4vAPgtWKioDmDX0xITf3RVC0VXDYOtwzIrZOFb0rw@gQlK9QK/EXw04eKdpp70cdnkYoq/esbfoRK5/KR7weg4iQjLz1P2c88@@vYjnNT1Qh0FWnJ0MIlrU9YNceuZPhqfz@ZzAVvDdenyTIdIVmUZb6d685WMZSmi1NMKgl7Xx7AJwRJsIIgDuCyGn0xEiTOP3Fbp0UnAQmunZKxZnIxPj5t0u1AmEXHXjiZyXogfpzGpEjWFktx/R3aIHF6G0z/0xeObRDzTXI6J4kNhTj@hGBdFp0g68Qpr@ctbrdb1Meg3pwGJ8S0lDppfwnsyOnBcw9ZNGKcM/OUmXvQ6Os93/5KxSpsOoWt5qkiDBYxkbDIYfGgjUWt1U3MOzms/NSbKQxnc4nDSnyxrREfomg0XVkXvxp@J/IPKm6lzX71Q4m8gLCHZyARCKY6UcPyebm7gV5uoRcPDff90q3h5foP)

Returns a negative number if the first version is smaller than the second one, a positive one if the first version is greater than the second one and `0` if they're equal.

Yep, that's some heavy work to "just" call a built-in!

### Credits

- -14 bytes, thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

Comment: I'm rather surprised by the length of this answer. Any golf is appreciated!

Comment: Can `i<x&i<y&t==0` become `i<x&i<y&t<1`?

Comment: @Cowsquack No, because `t` can hold any of `-1`, `0` or `1`.

Comment: I tried, but I'm only able to remove three bytes.. [228 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/ya2h38u5)

Comment: Thank @KevinCruijssen . I thought about doing this during lunch time, but hadn't any time to implement it yet. :) Also, it's 4 bytes, not 3 (we usually don't count the `;` after a lambda). ;-)

Comment: Found something more: [217 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/yc5c4daj)

Comment: That's probably it.. Already tried `try-finally` so the if-check can be simplified; tried return inside the loop if `t!=0`; tried using `Integer` and `i.compare(i.valueOf(...),i.valueOf(...))`; tried using generics like this `<T>T[]g(T s){return(T[])(s+"").replaceAll("(\\.0+)*$","").split("\\.");}`; etc. All are 2-6 bytes longer. If you (or anyone else) does find something more, let me know please. Curious to know what. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I could save a few bytes by getting rid of the transformation to a constant. So that any negative value means right is greater and any positive values means left is greater.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah nice. In that case you can use `Integer` and `i.valueOf` to save 2 more bytes: [201 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/ydbva2tb). NOTE (mainly for others reading): `.decode` instead of `.valueOf` doesn't work due to potential leading zeroes, which are interpret as octal numbers when using `.decode`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen While you posted your comment I was doing a similar thing by using `new Integer` instead, for the same amount of bytes.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah nice. In that case they can be `new Short` instead. I think it's save to assume version numbers will never be beyond 32000 in any regular versioning.. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No, I can't because "All numbers in a version number would be less than `2^16`." Short ranges from -(2^15) to 2^15-1.

Comment: @ceilingcat then the comparison between `0.0.1` and `0.1` (in that order) would return `0.0.1 > 0.1` and fail.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I could remove 105 bytes! How? Well, I found a built-in ;)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Rofl, nice one :D Didn't knew there was a builtin for that in Java without external libraries.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Actually, I'm playing currently playing with modules for a side-project. That's how I found it. I would never have found it in other circumstances ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>49</s> 40 bytes

```
+0|{~c[H,".",T]hị;T|ị;0|0}ᵐz{h-0&t↰₀|h-}
```

...It's still rather unimpressively lengthy.

Expects a list of two strings. Uses `positive number / zero / negative number`
as `> / = / <`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X9ugprouOdpDR0lPSSckNuPh7m7rkBoQaVBjUPtw64Sq6gxdA7WSR20bHjU11GTo1v7/H61kYKAHQoZKOkpACggNlWL/BwEA)

### Explanation

**Splitting the inputs**

Given an input that does not unify with `[0, 0]`, such as `["1.02.0", "1.2.0.1.0"]`, the below segment outputs, e.g., `[[1, "02.0"], [1, "2.0.1.0"]]`.

```
                            # unify the input with...
+0                          # : a list whose sum = 0 (output is 0)
  |{                     }ᵐ # : OR a list that when mapped...
    ~c                      # : : if the input string unifies with a list of the form...
      [H,".",T]             # : : : e.g. "1.02.0", H = "1", T = "02.0"
               hị           # : : : coerce the head to an integer
                 ;T         # : : : append the string T
                            # : : : "1.02.0" -> [1, "02.0"]
                   |ị       # : : OR it unifies with an integer
                     ;0     # : : : append 0
                            # : : : "1" -> [1, 0]
                       |0   # : : OR it unifies with 0
                            # : : : 0 -> [0]
```

**Comparing the inputs**

Given, e.g., `[[1, "02.0"], [1, "2.0.1.0"]]`, zips the sublists into `[[1, 1], ["02.0", "2.0.1.0"]]` and compares the values in the head (`[1,1]`). Recur on the second sublist. Note that the zip predicate `z` cycles through shorter lists so that zipping with `[0,0]` is equivalent to zipping with `[0]`, hence the previous step unifies `0` with `0` without further values appended.

```
z             # zip the sublists
 {          } # unify the result (r) with...
  h           # : take the head of the result
   -          # : : subtract the second value from the first
    0         # : : if the difference unifies with 0...
     &t↰₀     # : : recur on the tail of r
         |h-  # : OR unify with the difference of the elements of the head
              # : (equivalent to returning early)
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>73</s> 68 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to @redundancy*

Takes input as `(a)(b)`. Returns \$0\$ for *equal*, a positive integer for *greater than* or a negative integer for *less than*.

```javascript
a=>b=>(a+[...b].fill`.`).split`.`.some((x,i)=>d=~b.split`.`[i]-~x)*d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDRboIwFIbv9xTkXLXbPLZNHZCsvIgxEQRMF2bNMItXvjprKYJTqwSSnvTr35/vK//N282P3h9mO1NWXa26XGWFykj@tkTEYoW1bpo1rim2@0Yf7Apb810RcnzXVGWlOhXjzlKvZqcjfS27jdm1pqmwMVtSExAQDQ8lwKeBRvN5lL1c0RwZMgjQ6g4NU/Z0NEQLlH0dOgz9BcEmHBcfcZLCQF9mf96hhyqehid/KS5pvnicnSCTo5MEJTxyEiPjo8EYE3juG51Hb5C5V0Cgid9mVpulmT8KwezzduRp/q/JTbY8G3a0vPJ9k52mKdoPenoY7A2BbMGcw8QB4zD17v4A)

Comment: Nice. If I've understood correctly, you can save bytes by substituting `replace` with `fill`. The operands for `-` are swapped since both must now be coerced to a number. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDRboIwFIbv9xTkXLXbPLZNHZCsvIgxEQRMF2bNMItXvjprKYJTqwSSnvTr35/vK//N282P3h9mO1NWXa26XGWFykj@tkTEYoW1bpo1rim2@0Yf7Apb810RcnzXVGWlOhXjzlKvZqcjfS27jdm1pqmwMVtSExAQDQ8lwKeBRvN5lL1c0RwZMgjQ6g4NU/Z0NEQLlH0dOgz9BcEmHBcfcZLCQF9mf96hhyqehid/KS5pvnicnSCTo5MEJTxyEiPjo8EYE3juG51Hb5C5V0Cgid9mVpulmT8KwezzduRp/q/JTbY8G3a0vPJ9k52mKdoPenoY7A2BbMGcw8QB4zD17v4A "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: @redundancy Good idea! (Not sure if my implementation exactly is what you had in mind, though.)

Comment: I assumed your intent was to append enough values coercible to 0 such that mapping over the substrings of `a` eventually cycles through those 0 values if `b` contains more number segments than `a`. It so happens that the shortest method of ensuring that is so is to split over a `b`-length string of '.' by leveraging the existing split applied to `a`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 87 bytes

```python
lambda*p:cmp(*zip(*map(lambda x,y:(x or 0,y or 0),*[map(int,u.split('.'))for u in p])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHbboMwDIavt6fIXRIUWSFKR0CjL8K4YKvQIhUatbQqe3mWExlMysmf/Tu2bObp@zKKpa8/lnM3fJ66zFRfgyHZj7bH0BkSMHqyuSJPdLkizmZ/UZY1LkCPE7vDzZz1RDBgSnvrvSM9ItNSShdn3tjEHg41DRaYIZy744hbhhqcAweeYJ2gR6svYQEyZHCvfZocDm@FKlev170nZ8wndhIRaX7YRSvg0jsUyM3vBfCQpgD1vwH4q5i7JTb5AuG@Wh6CN/JkxyuKZOxArq3E8LIswW5H4nMnE9xVrwKLRlS31euLudp5@XkQXB8x9Ho8kQdlPbHMTmv5BQ)

Outputs -1,0,1 for <,=,>, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 54 bytes

```
\d+
$*
+`^(.)(.*=)\1
$2
(.*=|^=.*)1.*
<
.*1.*=.*
>
\.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU3RCsIwDHzPXwgKXQchKZ1ridOf8HGMCfPBFxHx/2vSDpLcJXdcvs/f6/0oJ3dfcftoT2Xeejh66NfFYefQT93McAywuNuBO93RM3q4QEXd4AozQilBGBgJqaFUrixgVMnA7ozDeUy5HkxlMwazGeFBbwkpis4II5LqI6YWjHssWQVoSCzURKhTjEUNl1hf5JxRW3ZUMZC9SGrd2R8) Link includes test cases. Uses the separator value as the equality output, so for convenience the header converts the input separator to `=` but it could be anything not in `[.\d]`. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
+`^(.)(.*=)\1
$2
```

Repeatedly delete the first character from each side until they differ or one side runs out. This is much faster than trying to match prefixes, although possibly not golfier. At this point, the strings are in one of several forms, which need to be decoded to a comparison result.

1. If neither string contains a `1` then the result is `=`
2. If the left string starts with a `1` then the result is `>`
3. If the right string starts with a `1` then the result is `<`
4. If the left string is empty then the result is `<`
5. At this point the right string is empty so the result is `>`

Another way of thinking about this is that if one string contains a `1` and the other does not start with a `1` then that string is greater, however that turns out to be a byte longer.

```
(.*=|^=.*)1.*
<
```

Check for case 3, or case 4 without case 1.

```
.*1.*=.*
>
```

If the left string still contains a `1` at this point then it is greater.

```
\.
```

Otherwise delete any left over `.`s.

## Firefox Browser Console REPL, 19 bytes

```
Services.vc.compare
```

I believe this internal function performs the required comparison. It returns -1, 0, or 1.

Comment: I would suggest you post the Firefox chrome code as another answer...

Comment: btw, I'm not sure how Firefox chrome code count its bytes. Should `Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");` be counted?

Comment: @tsh That's why I added "Browser Console REPL"...

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>140</s>  134 bytes

This code outputs a negative, `0` or a positive for `<`,`=` or `>` respectively.

```c
i;n;p;q;g(char*s){for(i=n=0;*s&&++n&&*s-46;i=i*10+*s++-48);i=i;}f(char*a,char*b){for(p=q=0;*a+*b&&p==q;b+=n)p=g(a),a+=n,q=g(b);a=p-q;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLLboMwELznKyykUIzBshFJiBznJ3pMORhUUgvF4ZGeIr6d@kFoSItAuzuzM9jaLeNzWY6jZIo1rGXnoPwSXdjDe3XtAskVJyzsfR8h5fthH6dbJrkMKUFhj1CcZtDUbKicTkQ2FE7e8NbIBQoL3284b1mBuIINPwcCRkLnUavzAjLBm7hlw2jUoLxemnd5VoFUNyAhuK@AfmQVyAOBAHSft@9OgbfDG5sJzjXzIPgTcXxWHDUxrFbG9iKkCh7W9sxAnPJTkgM@gQDcvcSLPOoN0QxQTDD5BzSQpRZwglPrYJIXBcWb7S7bT@yLjjq/5MXNoXSz7M4wSQ2R4fQZ32FibXY4@3MBPJ@YmHfxHwcRqnniehesBQy1gNPEGqavV9nv91h/mpqypSwh5vSZdQRT8eAHN0M3SD2w2tVmrWq9VPWBbhhCNZyn5drM7ugRVoE41fmJ5JGNNIdsbms63VgF3pqSHqxLYOKH8iLwkPwuoEngRMwew2oYfwA)

## Edits:

- Saved 6 bytes thanks to ceilingcat !

Comment: The challenge states: "Use three constant distinct values;" Your code doesn't return constants.

Comment: @Olivier It states I can "Use three constant distinct values;" OR "Use positive number / zero / negative number, while zero means equal;"

Comment: My bad! You're correct.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 75 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{c=d=0;c,d=[a,b].map{|f|f.slice!(/\d*./).to_i}while''<a+b&&c==d;c<=>d}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHhaoMwFIX/@xSujNpu7jYJ6YyY@CJdGZpUJlgqtmOM6rO7G2NkmyRw/O7J9cTbfZbfY6XGl7yIy7tWRpFMx0Yd8PUI56K991VfwbWp9elhs3szT7Dbwu3yXg9fH3VziiJZPJfrtVbKZFqq3AzjioX@oYvKAwoEyD@qLPXepW4pA84cRUV9Bwr710SkE3VeaSnxHdivr7GF0v3iFUC4owK4z5AAmVskIP7mBZsPN7GLYQenCCYirj55vbLU304G3IcM@ZI3D9I0BdyoZ4UnZMCIzSZQz8p6V3Btm/q2ecR/Ps2i63EusVbdXIjCaJu14UHH1TSx4zD@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>16</s> 11 bytes

*-5 bytes from @Shaggy*

Outputs:

- negative number for `<`
- (`null` or `0`) for `=`
- positive number for `>`

---

```
N®q.Ãy_r-Ãf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3@/QukK9w82V8UW6h5vT/v9XMtQz0jMxVOKCMIyUuHTTAQ)

Comment: Would [this](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=rnEuw3lfci0gZ8Nm&input=WyIxLjIuNDEiLCIxLjIuNDIiXQotZw==) work?

Comment: @Shaggy Yep, It could be shorten to [10 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=rnEuw3lfci3DZg==&input=WyIxLjAuMC4xLjAiLCIxLjAwLjAwLjIiXQotZw==) outputing negative, null or 0, positive for `< = >` respectively but I dont know if the input can be taken as an array

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>105</s> <s>88</s> 80 bytes

*-17 bytes from @redundancy. Wow!*

*-8 bytes removing Math.sign. Thanks @tsh*

Returns a negative, zero or positive value

```javascript
f=(a,b,r=/(\d*).?(.*)/)=>a+b&&+((a=r.exec(a))[1]-(b=r.exec(b))[1]||f(a[2],b[2]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHfboMgFMav3VMYLxpo9QiETrxwe4Q9QNcLsNpsaWpj22UXfXcnf5olQmwTIEB@3zkfH9/yR57r/ut0yY7drhmGtkIyVWlf5ehzt8TwjmCJc1y9yZVaLFYIyaqH5repkcR4Q7cZUvcLZS5utxbJDdumalwwHurueO4ODRy6PWpRwpI0TmiCcRxFUZ7HH9fT9RLTlwlGgQAJoiSAGtAoHsMMuPWgd676nA8K69dClHcJmSiykMQZYk88kzmWrp@oLIBwgwvgIz370gKI9VGAmLDhtOE/SKKHdj/nxlKEag2xBR6laSHDe//qN@DMGuKB2D24LEsYp@bd1rPjd2BERyqsJ3eYNhr@AA)

Comment: 88 bytes using `exec` to split strings. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHRboMgFIav3VMYLxro9HggdOKF2xMse4CuF2i169Joo3bZRd/didAsUWObAAHy/ef8/HyrH9Vk9fHcBmW1z7uuSIjyU79OQvK5X1N4I7CmIU1e1XO6Wr2r9gua46EkRCU15L95RhSlW7YLSHq7SIeL67Ugast3ftovlHZZVTbVKYdTdSAF8bjnux7zKHUdxwlD9@NyvrQuexphDBBwFsUZdAAHxX2YgzAe9M5WX/LBYPMSyfgmwZEimJNYQ/yBZ3LLss0DlSWgGHAJoqcXXxoBGh8RyBE7nzb8B4l6aPdLbgyFTGvQFLiXpoEGfvKv0waCG0NiJvYJHMcx9FPzdjuxM@3AUUcqjSd7GDfq/gA "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: @redundancy Damn, thanks! thats a pretty cool trick

Comment: Maybe you want to remove the Math.sign to save some bytes by switching to positive / zero / negative values. And maybe a positive sign is required.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>116</s> 111 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Text
?s=map toInt(split"."s)
$a b= @(?a)(?b)
@[h:t][u:v]|h==u= @t v=h-u
@l[]=sum l
@[]l= ~(sum l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrBCoJAFEX38xUPa6GQUi2Dhy5qIbQIaicuXqYpzIzivBkKok9v0uJuzj33VrIm7VV/s7IGRZ32nRr6keHMt4N2q0v9YJEaVDQA97nm0Ayy4yAJTCSWBFeELEwpCtNrJLKi3XFZ2J0rXy2inTYGh21sRSaLEo1VIKdXKRHe4a9F/sw0sliA2wBCsEnWc4JZbH9ixkZPuBQ4w/RzW/@pGkl34@P86PdPTaqr/uUkiZt@VF8)

Outputs a negative number when the first argument is less than the second one, zero when they're equivalent, and a positive number when it is more than the second one.

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4+Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), <s>160 bytes (142+18)</s>, 155 bytes (142+13)

#### Import (13 bytes, including `;` to separate from the code):

This will import Foundation, but is 5 bytes shorter than `import Foundation`.

```swift
import UIKit;
```

#### Header (not counted: the code is non-recursive):

```swift
let f:(String,String)->ComparisonResult =
```

#### Code (142 bytes):

```swift
{var x={($0 as String).split{$0=="."}.count},a=$0,b=$1
while x(a)<x(b){a+=".0"}
while x(b)<x(a){b+=".0"}
return a.compare(b,options:.numeric)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLdaoMwGL33KULwwrAsjWJXLbU3Y3uA7XLsIna6BqxKjGtBfHaXNCZ1P6LIyfn5zid2Z17KeOKnthESPDd9/cEkb2qvKiQot8GrFLz@xOaF7vePzallgndN/VJ0fSVBBqbhiwlwyYbAp4B1YNaSrq24HHyaZZDAkRxUthwxy3yK88wPvfORVwW4BAztLkGOBnanhBSOjsg1wdCQW0IUshc1YCpLtyiCHDetbtttSd2fCsEPaJzevABGEAN7wRAivFo5vFd8SKhKxP/ymeFdwix2GsNHJJ6HGHALMfkhWT9sklRJrvzCvzO8G6D5ZQPjj5Z8uP7tTwiNXf@ExIsA3W9DqBugQPI3X61EzJYaUH3PLXS@OaChjoDUiG2G9puDOX/B2X5xdPuAMP65v/anaUrUc5VYYFO0P6J6w@Q6w4Lb/HePlI14YocjGECr/japfj0M/FCJlaGcEUJgnL4B)

#### Explanations

1. We append some trailing .0 for same number of components.
2. We compare components numerically.

#### Returned constants

- ComparisonResult.orderedSame for =
- ComparisonResult.orderedAscending for <
- ComparisonResult.orderedDescending for >

Comment: I'm not sure if we count the `import` statement, so I posted [a separate answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171111/26980) that doesn't require `Foundation` and with a bytes count in-between 142 bytes (not counting import) and 160 bytes (counting import).

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 155 bytes

#### Header (not counted: the code is non-recursive):

```swift
let f:(String,String)->Bool? =
```

#### Code

```swift
{let x:(String)->[Int]={$0.split{$0=="."}.map{Int($0)!}.reversed().drop{$0==0}.reversed()},a=x($0),b=x($1)
return a==b ?nil:a.lexicographicallyPrecedes(b)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLPa4MwFL73r8hCDwbcaxS7allaGOyw22DH0kNqYytkKtFtHeLf7hKj1naiJF@@H@89SfmTJlXQSlGhZO18VCrNTq5dyOPmJc/lFjHU1kZwGQSa2b1l1Z7VcwplIdNKbxjDgBv45EWtOWdOyUMDSnwLVYqjQ@Co8qKT0elx43J2MWL3YFaPzJSovlSGOGMHtM1SueYgxSWN85PixTmNuZS/70rE4ihK50CadjdzsI9dNDzYw8RdLEa80bwHFGivueeZ5ceEXjxqLO9D0Bex4Bpi8z1YPq3CSEs6fuJ/tvxYwPDTDqzfn/Le8t4fAg3G/kMIJgGmvxXQsYAG4f98PRLYKQ2g5u27MPn2gHomAlMrHjKM3x70@RNu6C/wrz8QB7fzG38URaC/TjKAIcX4fWomDLsaA7jW388gydUrj8@oRoW@geZ6uWjuabE2JD0iBDXtHw)

#### Explanations

- We trim trailing .0.
- We compare components numerically.

#### Returned constants

- nil for =
- true for <
- false for >

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 64 bytes

```
a=>b=>(e=i=>(g=v=>v.split`.`[i]||0)(a)-g(b)||!a[i]-1&&e(i+1))(0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLRboMgFIbv9xSMiwayeALGTs2GyZ5jWVLbUsNiqhPnle/uENSqrTNqOJyP/5zzh@@0SfWpUmXtXYuz7C6iS0VyFAmRQpl/JhqRNKDLXNUHOHyqr7ZllKTUy8iRtu1zarY8vttJol44pYTRLtVaVjUSqJI/v6qSBLsdTN@e3IpcCPYxReNDMMfjmqIEsQXJgQEb6CUphLhnJ93x5DbrQzC0MURW/FEHHPavYRQb2JGj6vs9OTVgSbw9lb8g@X5TMwIW3OaPIMCb84fA@M2rECL8r6vg/LIR69/ejnV9l2G8lzWRO4cfabrMWN1Rj2cKfJhNH8wcXWvGcQzms/AU2SprTZ/1TkU2N0WzPk/FVRe5hLzICP7Ic1RLXWtU9gpnczm7Pw)

With comments:

```
a=>b=>(                            // Main function takes arguments like ("1.2.42")("1.2.41")
    e=i=>                          // e(i) compares the ith number, returns >0, <0 or =0.
        (   g=v=>v.split`.`[i]||0  // g() returns the ith string or 0
        )(a)                       // call g(a)
        -g(b)                      // subtracting g(b) from g(a) casts strings to integer
        ||                         // If they are not equal return result now
        !a[i]-1 &&                 // recursion limited to a.length, always sufficient
        e(i+1)                     // next i
    )(0)                           // Start with i = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 55 bytes

```perl
sub c{@_<2?sprintf"%9d"x9,split/\./,pop:-(c(pop)cmp c(pop))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xY/fboIwFMbv@xQnDBOalFoaVFDAmex6u9mlCVHsnPEfsxhdCM/OWqDE7QXW0PLrd76efs3F5TCq5XUNWV0@pxGfy/yyOxUf1iDcWPeQyPywK4ZLOiT5OZ@6TuaoP86OObSEq/rpcj1BIWQhIVtJIdHtc3cQTvSyeF8kuEQAx2/HXhF7TWxB7C2Om6YzVXA6wSm/bk4ErgcxMEjAw5WblLaoSNaexFjbTTR3LGHghhK6VdxzkRVio7ZcbbfnoqHlySLqhji2t3PrbW9NrVdVOe8tTB7izFCF0lSHTVP4t4F4j15PCfIoo@yPGmvVePu6Vjn1easq8kwHj47GkyBs1NYbaZWZDvzhNt6r3qj3BpT5rRpQ32SYUNa1mNDgd16q86nJ9MdVh5aYSsTaeuM1pFXzugj5JiT4fd4EhWFI1VTckToRIc50tkBxR423/gE)

Answer (score 0):

### Burlesque - 17 bytes

```
wd{'.;;)ri}m[^pcm


blsq ) "2018.08.1 2018.08"wd{'.;;)ri}m[^pcm
1
blsq ) "0.0.1 0.1"wd{'.;;)ri}m[^pcm
-1
blsq ) "1.1.56789 1.2.0"wd{'.;;)ri}m[^pcm
-1
```

If you want output in '><=' then add `?i"<=>"j!!Q`.

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 88 bytes

Returns `0` for equal, a `positive integer` for greater than or a `negative integer` for less than.

```powershell
param($a,$b)+(($x=$a-split'\.')+($y=$b-split'\.')|%{$x[+$i]-$y[$i++]}|?{$_}|Select -f 1)
```

Less golfed test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param($a,$b)
$x=$a-split'\.'
$y=$b-split'\.'
$z=$x+$y|%{
    $x[+$i]-$y[$i++]
}|?{$_}|Select -first 1
+$z             # convert $null to 0

}

@(
    ,("2"         ,"1"         , 1)
    ,("1.0.0"     ,"1"         , 0)
    ,("1.0"       ,"1.0.0"     , 0)
    ,("1.2.42"    ,"1.2.41"    , 1)
    ,("1.1.56789" ,"1.2.0"     ,-1)
    ,("1.10"      ,"1.2"       , 1)
    ,("1.20"      ,"1.150"     ,-1)
    ,("18.04"     ,"18.4"      , 0)
    ,("7.010"     ,"7.8"       , 1)
    ,("1.0.0.1.0" ,"1.00.00.2" ,-1)
    ,("00.00.01"  ,"0.0.0.1"   , 1)
    ,("0.0.1"     ,"0.1"       ,-1)
    ,("42.0"      ,"4.2.0"     , 1)
    ,("999.999"   ,"999.999.1" ,-1)
    ,("2018.08.1" ,"2018.08"   , 1)
) | % {
    $v1,$v2,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $v1 $v2
    "$([Math]::Sign($result)-eq$expected): $result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: 1
True: 0
True: 0
True: 1
True: -1
True: 8
True: -130
True: 0
True: 2
True: -1
True: 1
True: -1
True: 38
True: -1
True: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), <s>277</s> 231 bytes

```
F(s,{t}){t=s.split('.').map(int.parse).toList();while(t.last<1)t.removeLast();return t;}f(a,b,{d,e,f,g,h,i=0}){d=F(b);e=F(a);g=d.length;h=e.length;f=h>g?g:h;for(;i<f;i++)if(e[i]!=d[i])return e[i]>d[i]?1:-1;return h>g?1:(h<g?-1:0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPJboMwEL33K1ypkm3VGdmINiQOyak99Q8QB7cYsJRNYNoD4ttTs5SQJkEwzPJm3vBkElXY0@mdlKy2Da1tWEJ53BpLMGAKO3UkZm/hqIpSU7CHD1NaQuVPbraaWNiq0q4EtVDo3eFbf6iuWmhbFXtkZZMSxT5ZnTDNUpaxnJmQO5YkfCefVGr3UlRmYQJbvc9sLvNQ/7lpmK@zTbZ03qEg0qxSaZ6fqUmJjkz8GCbO0oGpzazbxEYsZ@KPv@0XS5Kvss1MLDmVzWmnzJ7Q@gGhb1Ugi0IUOR@hCHsYDRdDWIxBH8VsQAngwPFNFL9A4XP32HKF8sDvaDuUCwS@xSjg5XUeLPCAOs@aXcLOBQfDd9b3pijxcmdYANwfdwnAx7e@cg5cjFrMIcD3FYNWkV4L3t5uvX@UfZ6LrsD7Hnw1bEz3KDGhnA7zpyr5F5pNUIvFAtyDu/wQgLjazOOtHIGruMIQnDdzoFg@OGvBHdM39ZUTUnUHDKFj4X4dgp/qlFQRj1kViZg2KFyjp7qKvLjBVDpg42xz@gU)

- -44 bytes by using variables to store length and using ternary in loop
- -2 bytes by removing the for brackets

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>54</s> 50 bytes

***-4 bytes** by using `$@` instead of `$1\ $2`*

```sh
eval {autoload,}' is-at-least $'{@,2\ $1}';<<<$?;'
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/tSwxR6E6sbQkPyc/MUWnVl0hs1g3sUQ3JzWxuERBRb3aMEZBxUjHCEga1qpb29jYqNhbq////99QzwAIgSSIZQBCRgA)</s>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/NaoQwFIXX5ikugxCFMSTBqb@l3ZRuCt111U1sIjMgE1DbRcVnt9GYTJlLAifHLyfH3@G8tFEcLepHdDCJ71F3WsjjjOEyJGJMOiWGEUI8PR/5J4RsxlVd1@FThZcYoVb3IKABCREKOLhhXr2igBFK6J39stmO9sBmc5JyaxvFfAgjp4csLzbb0m@bTV0I//8k9zY73eic0NTaOUl9k4zQPSUj@V1vstY0m66LryFWUlOMWsDSTq62@09Dp64spL63oYuiIGabw67MHUNzulbMzWFXGx1XIDUK1NdZw@FD9cNFX4cSwinqS0bLWMw33cwHR773UvUmwJDSmThxg1HQQiggbNynRzcYSX1Vyx8)

This `eval`s to the following eight statements:

```sh
autoload is-at-least $@       # loads the "is-at-least" function
<<<$?                         # success, prints 0
autoload is-at-least $2 $1    # redundant
<<<$?                         # success, prints 0
is-at-least $@                # exits 1 if $1 < $2
<<<$?
is-at-least $2 $1             # exits 1 if $2 < $1
<<<$?
```

So the three unique values are:

```sh
 cmp |  value
-----+------------------------------------------
  =  |  0<newline>0<newline>0<newline>0<newline>
  <  |  0<newline>0<newline>1<newline>0<newline>
  >  |  0<newline>0<newline>0<newline>1<newline>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ṣ€”.Vz0I¬ÞḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY@xCsIwEIb3PoWDi8txCdGm0HYXnH0DF3Fw1UldHNwUxEFFdHVUsXSr6HukLxIvpglqyMHPd/9d/vR7g8FIa5Wdytm5nOygO8Z2cX7s1f2oVX4prkk5vdWfq2FdZevOa/6Yq@yg8kU52cZpQhON51JlG615zR3mVRowQMA/mhjqvL5vKAfBLSXF3AYGzVYoow@13thQdBv412vcU9b0XgkoLJUgXIYQsFoRgvzNCyYfFZrLaYNVSInQ9j9epwx1v4sD4ULWhM@bBlEUARXpStFEHHA02STpShnvGw)

May be stretching the rules a little, but going by [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884/66833) I/O default, it's allowed. This uses the output presentation:

> Use positive number / zero / negative number, while zero means equal;

but the output is wrapped as a singleton array

### How it works

```
ṣ€”.Vz0I¬ÞḢ - Main link. Takes a pair of versions [a, b] on the left
 €          - Over each:
ṣ ”.        -   Split on "."
    V       - Evaluate each numeric string to a number
     z0     - Transpose, filling with 0s
       I    - Take the differences of each pair
        ¬Þ  - Sort by logical NOT
              This shuffles 0 to the end and preserves the order of everything else
          Ḣ - Take the first element
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-plF\.`, 50 bytes

```perl
@b=<>=~/\d+/g;1while@F+@b&&!($_=shift@F<=>shift@b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98hydbGzrZOPyZFWz/d2rA8IzMn1cFN2yFJTU1RQyXetjgjM63Ewc3G1g7CStL8/99Qz0APiLmg9L/8gpLM/Lzi/7oFOW4xegA)

Takes input on two lines.

| Output | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First version is greater |
| 0 | Versions are equal |
| -1 | Second version is greater |